# How can I convert a 'Collection<Map<String,String>>' to 'Map<String,String>'?

Tags: java, collections

I want to convert from `Collection<Map<String,String>>` to `Map<String,String>`.

When I tried to do this way,

```
Map<String,String> m = (Map<String,String>)map.values();
```

where,
map is of type `Map<String,Map<String,String>>`

I'm getting

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.TreeMap$Values cannot be cast to java.util.Map

What is it trying to say? I'm not able to get it and how do I correctly convert from `Collection<Map<String,String>>` to `Map<String,String>`?

Comment: Collection<Map<String,String>> to Map<String,String> the code is:  
Map<String,String> m = (Map<String,String>)map.values();

Comment: It's unclear what you're saying: map variable is of type `Collection<Map<String,String>>` or `Map<String,Map<String,String>>`? If you get a ClassClastException, I think that variable type isn't the one you expect. Where does it come from?

Comment: map is of type Map<String,Map<String,String>>.When I tried to do this Map<String,String> m = map.values();  I got an exception saying "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Collection<Map<String,String>> to Map<String,String>".So I did this:                                              
 Map<String,String> m = (Map<String,String>)map.values(); After doing this I got an exception again saying "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.TreeMap$Values cannot be cast to java.util.Map"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this small snippet to put all the values into a single map:

```
Map<String, String> result = new TreeMap<>();
for(Map<String, String> value : map.values()) {
    result.putAll(value);
}
```

Though this will just overwrite duplicate keys with a new value if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's collection then you should think as it's collection of objects.
Then proceed the  iteration,  for each object,  you shall put it in  the map

```
 public Map<String, String> getMapsFromArrayOfMaps( Collection<Map<String,String>> maps ) {
    Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();      
    maps.forEach(map->result.putAll(map));        
    return result ;

}
```